# Java code not recognizing my XML filename

Tags: java, android, xml

My issue is that Android Studio is telling me it "cannot resolve the symbol 'Board'" in the code below. I assume the fix is to tell Android Studio that Board references Board.xml but I'm note quite sure how this is done.

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class ChessBoard extends ActionBarActivity {
View.OnClickListener clickListener;

public ImageView block2 = (ImageView) Board.findViewById(R.id.block2);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.Board);
```

Comment: Most likely, you do not have a layout resource named `Board.xml`. Note that resources are usually in lowercase in Android.

Comment: Well you don't have a variable nor class named Board imported. Anyway I don't think that findViewbyId will work at this position. It has to be called after setContentView().

Comment: Resource names have to be lowercase. This is not a guideline. Its a requirement.